# How can i put an experiession to minimize using choco solver?

Tags: solver, choco

I use choco solver version 2.1.5, and I want to make an experience to minimize the sum of my variables. How I can do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you downloaded that version from sourceforge: there, we are advised to visit
http://choco-solver.org where we can download more recent ones.

```
With the more recent version 4.10.7, released on Oct 11 2021, 
you may experiment with something like this:


    Model model = new Model();
            
    IntVar x = model.intVar("x", 3, 10, false);
    IntVar y = model.intVar("y", 2, 20, false);
    IntVar sum = model.intVar("sum", 1, 50, false);
    
    model.arithm(x, "+", y, "=", sum).post();
            
    Solver solver = model.getSolver();  
    model.setObjective(Model.MINIMIZE, sum);
    
    while (solver.solve()) {
        System.out.println(" x = " + x.getValue());
        System.out.println(" y = " + y.getValue());
        System.out.println(" sum = " + sum.getValue());
    } 


It will print:

    x = 3
    y = 2
    sum = 5
```